# HttpRequestInterceptor in AndroidHttpClient. I'm confused!

Tags: android, http

I'm using AndroidHttpClient in my app. Now I need to use Basic authorization for requests.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html

In documentation they say I can use HttpRequestInterceptor but I can't figure HOW I can do that. There is no method to add this interceptor. Ideally I wanted to add it like they do here:
http://dlinsin.blogspot.com/2009/08/http-basic-authentication-with-android.html

Anyone knows why it doesn't work for me or Google documentation wrong?

Comment: This is a [documentation bug](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CGgQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fandroid%2Fissues%2Fdetail%3Fid%3D28438&ei=4CGtT7TUFonl8QO02dnlCg&usg=AFQjCNEMo2p22Z95epN_n4m-kHFF8YKVPA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it's not possible and obviously documentation wrong.. Had to go with plain HttpClient to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old but for the benefit of anyone stumbling on this (like I did), you can roll the header yourself with `HttpGet` object. Like so :

```
httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode(username+":"+password));
```